# Why does my DirectInput8 stack overflow?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, directx, directinput

The overall program is too complex to display here. Basically, just pay attention to the [green highlights in my recent git commit](https://github.com/TheBuzzSaw/libxpg/commit/d1a7a7d7f570f4ccfaf470f56ab926dbabf7a3e4). I am very new to DirectInput, so I expect I've made several errors. I have very carefully studied the MSDN documentation, so I promise I'm not just throwing this out there and stamping FIX IT FOR ME on it. :)

Basically, I think I have narrowed down my problem to the area of code around Engine::getEvent (line 238+). I do not understand how these functions work, and I've messed with certain pieces to achieve different results. My goal here is to simply read in keyboard events directly and output those raw numbers to the screen (I will deal with the numbers' meaning later). The problem here relates to KEYBOARD_BUFFER_SIZE. If I make it small, the program seems to run fine, but it outputs no events. If I make it big, it runs a bit better, but it starts to slow down and then freeze (the OpenGL window just has a rotating color cube). How do I properly capture keyboard events?

I checked the return values on all the setup steps higher in the code. They all return DI_OK just fine.

Comment: Including the repeating portion of the stack at the time it overflows could be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be okay (according to [this tutorial, which I have used in the past](http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/directinput.html)). The use of several stack-based arrays is questionable, but shouldn't be too much of an issue (unless you start having lots of concurrent getEvent calls running).

However, your best bet would be to [stop using DirectInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165230/should-i-use-directinput-or-windows-message-loop/2168067#2168067) and start using [Windows Raw Input](http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/raw_input.html). It's best to make this switch early (ie, now) rather than realise later on that you really need to use something other than DI to get the results you want.

Comment: Whoa, I had no idea the DirectInput was that dead. You are right. WRI is more than adequate to do the job. Thank you!