# JoyStick input without DirectInput via WinForms, WPF or Metro?

Tags: winforms, input, microsoft-metro, hid, joystick

is it possible to get JoyStick input (WITHOUT DirectInput) from WinForms, WPF or Metro events?  Or from the WinProc callback maybe using the HID?
NOTE: The reason i'm being broad in the API's i'm asking about is because if I can find a solution in one I can probably port it to whatever I need.

I haven't found a clear answer on google and the reason I ask is because iv'e heard the preferred method of getting Keyboard and Mouse input is by using the Window event system.... So I thought it would be nice to have JoyStick input work the same way.

If this is possible with the HID (which im sure it is) could someone point me in a good starting direction for research?

**EDIT: I found "Raw input" might be my solution:** [Raw Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645543%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165230/should-i-use-directinput-or-windows-message-loop Not sure if its a duplicate but discusses the preferred method. It has a example that you could probably get tailoring to fit your needs straight away.

Comment: Tnx that actually got me where I wanted to be! The post wasn't for JoyStick input directly but I did see a post below that led me too "About Raw Input" "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645543%28VS.85%29.aspx"